# QPixmap & QRubberBand scaling troubles

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qrubberband

I have a "working" example but a few issues I can not seem to figure out. I have calculated the topLeft and bottomRight coordinates inside the rubber band and converted them to the widgets coordinates. However the pixmap.copy() does not copy those coordinates. The shifting global and widget coordinates systems are confusing so I assume I am not understanding the coordinate system properly.

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QRubberBand
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout, QSizeGrip
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(526, 478)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("ava.jpg"))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 526, 25))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Resizeable QLabel Example"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Crop"))


class Test_Resize(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test_Resize, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

    def run(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.cropImage)
        self.band = Resizable_rubber_band(self.label)
        self.band.move(50, 50)
        self.band.resize(200, 266)
        self.band.setMinimumSize(30, 30)

    def cropImage(self):
        rect = self.band.getCoverage()
        # copy(QRect( x, y, width, height))
        self.label.setPixmap(self.label.pixmap().copy(rect))
        self.label.repaint()


class Resizable_rubber_band(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Resizable_rubber_band, self).__init__(parent)
        # tell QSizeGrip to resize this widget instead of top-level window
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.SubWindow)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.grip1 = QSizeGrip(self)
        self.grip2 = QSizeGrip(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.grip1, 0, Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.grip2, 0, Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.rubberband = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.rubberband.move(0, 0)
        self.rubberband.show()
        self.show()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        # force 4h x 3w aspect ratio using QSize
        # if width < height: height = 1.333 * width
        # if width > height: width = height / 1.333
        # width = self.width()
        # height = self.height()
        # if(width < height):
        #     height = int(width * 1.333)
        # else:
        #     width = int(height / 1.333)
        # self.rubberband.resize(QSize(width, height))
        self.rubberband.resize(self.size())

    def getCoverage(self):
        localCoords = self.contentsRect()
        print("localCoords: ", localCoords)
        TL = self.mapToGlobal(localCoords.topLeft())
        BR = localCoords.bottomRight()
        # TL+BR to get width & height
        widgetCoords = QRect(TL, TL+BR)
        print("widgetCoords: ", widgetCoords)
        return widgetCoords


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
program = Test_Resize()
program.run()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enable the [scaledContents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#scaledContents-prop) property:

```
self.label.setScaledContents(True)
```

the coordinates of the `QPixmap` do not correspond to the pixels of the `QLabel`, for example let's say that the `QPixmap` is 20 by 20 and the `QLabel` 20 by 10 then it will have to be transformed at the height of the pixmap from 20 to 10.

The first thing to do is to convert global coordinates to `QLabel` coordinates with `self.label.mapFromGlobal()`, and then transform the rectangle by scaling the width and height proportional to the initial change.

```
def cropImage(self):
    rect = self.band.getCoverage()
    r = QRect(self.label.mapFromGlobal(rect.topLeft()), rect.size())
    px = self.label.pixmap()
    tr = QtGui.QTransform()
    tr.scale(px.size().width()*1.0/self.label.size().width(), px.size().height()*1.0/self.label.size().height())
    r = tr.mapRect(r)
    self.label.setPixmap(px.copy(r))
```

Comment: `r = tr.mapRect(r)` r has data going into mapRect but the return QRect is empty. Even when I manually enter data the mapRect returns empty. If I do `r = QRect(tr.map(r.topLeft()), rect.size())` I get output but I don't think its the right mapping at all...

Comment: Wow, I never would have thought scale NEEDED a float, you would think an int would be just as good. This code works for setScaledContents(True) but when False it returns some incorrect selections. Ill work on that next so I have a more versatile module.